# Full error : Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.Def

Tags: android, android-studio

Full error:
Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler :23

This is my Gradle file. It is "gradle.build":

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdk 32
    buildToolsVersion '32.1.0 rc1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.amedina.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To fix it, change `compile` to `implementation` like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 after I change them into "implementation". What should I do now?

Comment: Use this `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'` as support libraries are deprecated.

Comment: If you still want to use `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'` then you need to add `android.enableJetifier=true` in your `gradle.properties` file. 
But I recommend you should use `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'` instead `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'`.